# Check if class constructor extends another class

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

How can I check if a class constructor extends another class, without constructing the object? IE by constructor reference.

Example

```
class A {

}

class B extends A {

}

var b = B;

if(typeof b === B)
```

Comment: After you do `b = B`, then it will always be `typeof b === typeof B` because `b` and `B` have the same value, thus the same `typeof`.  Also, `typeof` any constructor is always function.

Comment: Seems like a duplicate of this?

Comment: Correct. Answer is `A.prototype instanceof B`

Comment: Try `A.prototype instanceof B.prototype` to see if A constructor derives from B.

Comment: İf you want to know if a class inherited from Object or another class then use this. This will return false `B.__proto__ === Function.prototype` and this will return true `A.__proto__ === Function.prototype`

Comment: @user2410532 It should be `B.prototype instanceof A`. Please have a look my answer below.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can check this with help of `instanceof` as below.

```js
class A {

}

class B extends A {

}

class C {

}


console.log(B.prototype instanceof A);
console.log(C.prototype instanceof A);

// With instance
var b = new B();

console.log(b instanceof B);
console.log(b instanceof A);
console.log(b instanceof C);
```

Comment: I'll add this to my question - but I need to know without the object being constructed,

Comment: @user2410532 I have updated the code for this, please have a look

Comment: @jfriend00 Execute the snippet and check the answer please